# jquery event doesn't work inside meteor js handlebars

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have to display divs depending on user profile, both of divs appears as expected but the jquery events (inside a separate file) doesn't working , but if I remove the "if else condition" , the jquery events work correctly, thanks.

I've tried to put the divs inside new template but it also doesn't work.

```
<!-- home profile template -->
{{# if bandprofile  currentUser.profile.type }}
      <div id="bandnamediv" class="userinforow">
        <span>Band name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="bandnameinput" class="oldinfo bld " value="   {{currentUser.profile.bandName}}"/>
       <span class="savebandname">save</span>
    </div>
{{/if}}
{{# if userprofile currentUser.profile.type }}
       <div id="firstnamediv" class="userinforow">
          <span class="oldinfo bld">First name: </span>
          <input type="text" id="firstnameinput" class="oldinfo" value="{{currentUser.profile.firstname}}"/>
         <span class="savefirstname bld oldinfo">save</span>
       </div>
 {{/if}}
 <!--end home profile template-->
```

the template helpers

```
Template.homeprofile.helpers({ 
    bandprofile: function(usertype){ 
      if(usertype === "band") { return true; }
      else {return false;} 
  },
  userprofile: function(usertype){
   if(usertype === "costumer"){ return true; }
   else  {return false;}
 }
 });
```

external jquery file:

```
$('.savefirstname').click(function(){
    alert('save first name');
    /*other things*/
 });
 $('.savebandname').click(function(){
    alert('save band name');
    /*other things*/
 });
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to use jQuery instead of a helper?

Comment: @smoksnes i put all the the jquery tricks inside a separate file so the helpers will be not overlowded with those kind of events

Comment: So using native `Template.homeprofile.events` is not an option? Not a `helper`, but `events`.

Comment: @smoksnes in the external js file i have a bunch of  front end events  like : hide , show ,  toggles , transitions . is it recommended to them put all the inside Template.homeprofile.events

Comment: Neither `hide`, `show`, or `toggle` are events. They are methods. `click`, `blur`, `change` are events, and they should be in the `.events`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [events](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events) instead. It will probably be more easily to read, based on the meteor naming convention.

```
Template.homeprofile.events({
  'click .savefirstname': function(e, template){
        alert('save first name');
        /*other things*/
  }
  'click .savebandname': function(e, template){
      alert('save band name');
      /*other things*/
  }
});
```

From the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#eventmaps).

> An event map is an object where the properties specify a set of events
>   to handle, and the values are the handlers for those events.

...

> Event types and their uses include: **click**, **change**, **focus**, **blur**...

So, yes, I would say that events should be included in `Template.homeprofile.events`, based on the premises you defined in the question, where you try to bind an event (`click`).

Otherwise, if you really want to use jQuery for your events you could probably use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click`. Meteor renders the content dynamically, which probably is why your event listener isn't picking it up.

```
$('body').on('click', '.savefirstname', function(){
    alert('save first name');
    /*other things*/
 });

$('body').on('click', '.savebandname', function(){
    alert('save band name');
    /*other things*/
 });
```

Comment: it's working. `$('.wrapperdiv').on('click', '.savefirstname', function(){
    alert('save first name');
    /*other things*/
 });`